# Android app crashing due to Exception in runtime in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, runtimeexception, android-looper

This is my XML Code:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/simple_sales_inventory_using_android"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/product_name" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/quantity" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtsub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@string/fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/subtotal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtpay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@string/fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/payment" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtbal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:ems="10"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:textColor="@string/fff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/balance" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="@string/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tb1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="360dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tbrow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/product_name"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/price"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/qty"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/t4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/total"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not see any errors in XML code or in Java Code.

This is my Java Code:

```java
package com.example.simpleinventory;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> data3 = new ArrayList<>();
    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3,ed4,ed5,ed6;
    Button b1;

    public MainActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1=findViewById(R.id.ed1);
        ed2=findViewById(R.id.ed2);
        ed3=findViewById(R.id.ed3);
        ed4=findViewById(R.id.txtsub);
        ed5=findViewById(R.id.txtpay);
        ed6=findViewById(R.id.txtbal);
        b1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        ed5.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher () {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                int subtotal = Integer.parseInt(ed4.getText().toString());
                int pay = Integer.parseInt(ed5.getText().toString());
                int bal = pay - subtotal;
                ed6.setText(String.valueOf(bal));
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                add();
               }
        });
    }
        public void add() {
        int tot;
        String prodname = ed1.getText().toString();
        int price = Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString());
        int qty = Integer.parseInt(ed3.getText().toString());
        tot = price*qty;

        data.add(prodname);
        data1.add(String.valueOf(price));
        data2.add(String.valueOf(qty));
        data3.add(String.valueOf(tot));

        TableLayout table = findViewById(R.id.tb1);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TextView t1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t3 = new TextView(this);
            TextView t4 = new TextView(this);

            String total;
            int sum =0;

            for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
            {
                String pname = data.get(i);
                String prc = data1.get(i);
                String qtyy = data2.get(i);
                total = data3.get(i);

                t1.setText(pname);
                t2.setText(prc);
                t3.setText(qtyy);
                t4.setText(total);
                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(data3.get(i));
            }

            row.addView(t1);
            row.addView(t2);
            row.addView(t3);
            row.addView(t4);
            table.addView(row);

            ed4.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            ed1.setText("");
            ed2.setText("");
            ed3.setText("");
            ed1.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

I'm getting 0 compile errors but I get a runtime error in Logcat.

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpleinventory/com.example.simpleinventory.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.simpleinventory:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.simpleinventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class EditText
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.simpleinventory:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.simpleinventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88 in com.example.simpleinventory:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class EditText
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #fff from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c001e: .xml extension required
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1195)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadComplexColorFromName(ResourcesImpl.java:1013)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:1092)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1062)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:599)
        at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3961)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1064)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:74)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1551)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1602)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1061)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.simpleinventory.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7809)
2020-11-02 13:08:17.527 8788-8788/com.example.simpleinventory E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7798)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2017)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: you are missing to add this line in your onCreate function setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename);

Comment: extend your mainactivity

Comment: show you full mainActivity  code

Comment: @wahdatkashmiri it is my full main activity code and it is extended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is reported from line 88 in the activity_main.xml file, I see that your textColor is refering to a string, can you verify that this part is correct.

```
android:textColor="@string/fff"
```

It should be a color i.e :

```
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
```

Can you post your strings.xml?

Comment: But the android:textColor="@string/fff" is on 144th line.

Comment: <resources>
  <string name="app_name">SimpleInventory</string>
  <string name="simple_sales_inventory_using_android">Simple Sales Inventory using Android</string>
  <string name="product_name">Product Name</string>
   <string name="price">Price</string>
   <string name="quantity">Quantity</string>
   <string name="subtotal">Subtotal</string>
   <string name="fff">#fff</string>
   <string name="payment">Payment</string>
   <string name="balance">Balance</string>
   <string name="total">Total</string>
   <string name="add">Add</string>
   <string name="qty">qty</string>
</resources>

Answer (score 1):

you aren't setting your content at all, thus all `findViewById` are returning `null`...

add `setContentView` method just after `super.onCreate` call (and before all `findViewById`s), point on your posted XML file (`R.layout.filename`)